# what are the logistical steps to use iPad2 ad-hoc distribution for beta testing?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I understand the principles, but I need some additional help with the specific steps.  I have the provisioning profile for ad-hoc, now I want to tell a beta tester to "send me the UDID of their iPad2 and I will email a copy of my application that you can install on your iPad2 through iTunes."  Some of the testers will be geographically far away, so I cannot do any tethered iPad2 device provisioning or preparation.  Is it possible to list out the steps?

Something simple like this:

1. cut n' paste the Tester's UDID into .... XCode Organizer or Dev Portal
2. click n' zap the application with the UDID's new provisioned certificate
3. email the zapped app and a certificate to the Tester
4. Tester downloads the email attachments
5. Tester opens up iTunes and discovers the downloaded application and syncs it to the iPad2

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend [Testflight](http://testflightapp.com) for testing. It simplifies almost all steps of ad-hoc distribution, including collecting UDIDs and notifying testers of updates.

Comment: interesting .. is there a way to do this without a 3rd-party drop box?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by drop box, but if you don't want to rely on third parties I think @cortez's answer should be satisfactory.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand, or I read too quickly, was that both of these answers promote dropping my App image on a 3rd-party web site (i.e., the dropbox) and it is downloaded from there.  For our test distribution, I want to use an internal website.  I will read again as I am starting back on this part of the project this week.

Comment: The guide @cortez posted is for putting the .ipa and provisioning files on your own website.

Answer (score 1):

These steps should work but I would advise you to use a different approach. Don't send the App via Email try http://www.paradeofrain.com/2010/11/taking-the-pain-out-of-ad-hoc-testing/
("Distribute for Enterprise" can now be used by every Developer). This way of distributing your App is much simpler for the user.

The user can go to the URL, install the Provisioning Profile (only once) and then install the App.

Comment: interesting .. is there a way to do this without a 3rd-party drop box?  I agree with your point about using a website versus email -- good suggestion.